# make a specific page LTR while Sass is set for RTL (Zurb Foundation)

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, direction

My problem is with elements such as dropdowns.

the javascript is responsible for placing the dropdown, and Im looking for a way to let it know I want it to unfold left-to-right.

Same goes for the "after" pseudo-element, of that little arrow on the button.

This is a picture of how it looks now:
Any way to achive this?[image: Current]